# sugarcrm report

Tags: report, sugarcrm

In Sugarcrm Reports , How to Show opportunity amount in the user entered /actual currency, rather user preference currency. Struggling to find solution, any hint or help would be great helpful

Answer (score 1):

Please tell whether you are using Sugarcrm Edition Or Professional. and if You are using edition then which report module you are using?
In Case Of Professional  Edition , there is option to select the opportunity amount in the side bar and we can easily use them and their amount

Thanks